# How do I use peaks with an audio coming from the back-end in React Wavesurfer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wavesurfer.js

I have a problem using back-end media elements with peaks in this library
the peaks stopped working or did not appear when I try to get the audio from a database connected to the back-end...
on the other hand, when I use the audio directly on the client-side the peaks work just fine because I didn't have to use media elements with this option!

Does anyone have an idea?

here is a code snippet...

```js
 wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
      container: waveformRef.current,
      waveColor: "#747993",
      height: 90,
      responsive: true,
      progressColor: "#393F65",
      normalize: true,
      backend: "MediaElement",
      plugins: [
        RegionsPlugin.create({
          dragSelection: {
            slop: 5,
            color: "hsla(9, 100%, 64%, 0.1)",
          },
        }),
        TimelinePlugin.create({
          container: "#timeline",
          formatTimeCallback: formatTimeCallback,
          timeInterval: timeInterval,
          primaryLabelInterval: primaryLabelInterval,
          secondaryLabelInterval: secondaryLabelInterval,
          primaryColor: "#2A045A",
          secondaryColor: "#747993",
          primaryFontColor: "#2A045A",
          secondaryFontColor: "#747993",
          formatTime: "HH:MM:SS",
        }),
      ],
    });

    wavesurfer.load(audioUrl);
```

Comment: Please don't post your code as a tiny image. Just paste it in to the post in a code block.

Comment: yes i added the code snippet up there if you guys wanna check it out

Comment: Can I ask how you are getting the preloading peaks from the audio in the first place?